# why the django choice field wont set the inital value?

Tags: python, django, backend

i have a choice field like below

```
def status_field():
    return forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[
            (len(contract_status := Contract.Status.choices), 'all'),
            *contract_status
        ],
        widget=forms.Select(CUSTOM_SELECT_ATTRS),
        label='status',
        initial=Contract.Status.ACCEPTED
    )
```

Which is for Conract model and uses its Status Choice list which is like below

```
class Status(models.IntegerChoices):
    PENDING = 1, 'pending'
    ACCEPTED = 2, 'active'
    REJECTED = 3, '...'
    TERMINATED = 4, '...'
    ON_HOLD = 5, '...'
    FINISHED = 6, '...'
```

my form looks like this :

```
class FilterForm(BaseFilterForm):
   __fields = (
    'contract_status',
    ...)

    contract_status = contract_status_field()
```

i want the inital value to be active but it does not change i have tried to set it as 2 or {2 ,'active'} and Contrac.Status.ACCEPTED
also i have tried to change it's value inside **init** . but it did not work !
Why ? how to do this?

Comment: There will be *two* items with value `6`: `FINISHED` and `'all`.

Comment: Can you share *how* you use the form field in the (`Model`)`Form`?